# Creating a keyboard hook for a Java program that sits in the System Tray

Tags: java, keyboard, system, handle, system-tray

Basically I have a java program that runs in the system tray and would like to add make it so if the user pressed say CTRL+SHIFT+1 it selects one of the right click options of the java program that sits in the tray.

I guess what I'm looking for is a tutorial on doing this, or what the simplest approach would be.  I have never done something like this before, so possibly some sort of noobie tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: If this is for a Windows environment, consider using AutoIt3 for this.

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I am looking for at all. The closest thing I have found so far is JIntellitype but that has issues when I try to run as a jar.

Answer (score 2):

so , creating a keyboard hook isn't as easy as it looks , java doesn't provide a direct way to interact with the system events for purposes of security ; as it might lead to serious problems concerning the JVM , sysytem's memory and the portability of Java Framework..

you have 4 ways to make global keyboard hooks :

1- Learn [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI) / [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) , and I prefer JNA since its much easier than JNI , in both cases you shall deal with .dll files.

2 - Use JIntellitype , which - as you said - issues some problems.

3- the elegant solution by Sergei Biletnikov [here](http://biletnikov-dev.blogspot.com/2009/09/global-hotkeys-for-java-applications_25.html).

4- ignore Java , and try Autoit V3 ( I'm not 100% sure about it , but I think you could send signals/events from Autoit to your Java app , so Autoit would just work as a bridge that catches the global key strokes)